# C# auto filling inputbox in gecko webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, browser, gecko

I've been trying to fill some inputboxes with data using the following code:

```
        GeckoHtmlElement checkElement = null;
        GeckoDocument checkDoc = GeckowebBrowser.Window.Document;                        
        checkElement = checkDoc.GetHtmlElementById("username");
        if (checkElement!=null)
            {
                checkElement.InnerHtml = username;
            }
```

The above code finds the correct element and sets InnerHtml to 'username' but I get nothing on the screen. Using breakpoints I confirmed that the InnerHtml was changed according to the plan. I also tried changing .TextContent (instead of .InnerHtml) but the result was the same. The Html code goes like this:

```
<input id="username" class="inputboxclass" type="text" name="myusername">
```

I use C# winforms .NET 4.5 and geckoFX 16 (XulRunner 16).

Edit: Here is the code that works (thanks to RENE Victor's suggestion)

```
checkElement.SetAttribute("value", username);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in a standalone text file and open it in a browser:

```
<input type="text" value="5">fdfuhsi</input>
```

As you see you want to modify the vale, not the InnerHtml.